# Edit Text in Custom Listview Adapter Loses Value on Scroll

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a custom list view adapter where my edit text changes up its value on own and if one row is filled with some value, it gets on all the other rows also.

Here's My Adapter
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

```
using Android.App;
 using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace Kites
{
public class Marks 
{
    // add any if you need more

    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string MarksScored { get; set; }
}
public class MarksListViewAdapter : BaseAdapter<Marks>
{
    private List<Marks> mstuduentmarks;

    private Context mcontext;

    public MarksListViewAdapter (Context context, List<Marks> stud)
    {
        mstuduentmarks = stud;
        mcontext = context;
    }

    public override int Count 
    {
        get 
        {
            return mstuduentmarks.Count;
            //              return mattendence.Count;

        }
    }
    public override long GetItemId (int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public override Marks this[int position] 
    {
        get 
        {
            return mstuduentmarks [position];
            //              return mattendence [position];

        }
    }



    public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) // otherwise create a new one
            view = LayoutInflater.From(mcontext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.listview_Marks, null, false);

        // set view properties to reflect data for the given row
        TextView txtStudent = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textStudentNameTeacherMarks);
        txtStudent.Text = mstuduentmarks[position].StudentName;
        EditText txtMarks = view.FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.editTextTeacherMarks);
        txtMarks.Text = mstuduentmarks[position].MarksScored;

        txtMarks.TextChanged += (sender, e) => 
        {
            mstuduentmarks[position].MarksScored = txtMarks.Text;
        };


        return view;
    }






}
}
```

Comment: Try Recycler view it has in build view holder that will help your case.

Comment: How do i do that sir?

Answer (score 0):

Following code you can easily proceed your click events with any element :)

```
public class HomeRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {


private List<String> mItemList;

RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

Context context;
HomeItemViewHolder mHomeItemholder;

public HomeRecyclerAdapter(List<String> itemList) {
    mItemList = itemList;
}


public class HomeItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView mImage;


    public HomeItemViewHolder(View parent) {
        super(parent);

        mImage = (ImageView) parent.findViewById(R.id.Image); 

    }

}

public HomeRecyclerAdapter(List<String> itemList, Context context, RecyclerView mRecyclerView) {
    this.mItemList = itemList;
    this.context = context;
    this.mRecyclerView = mRecyclerView;


}


@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Context context = parent.getContext();

    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_home, parent, false);


    return new HomeItemViewHolder(view);

}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

    mHomeItemholder = (HomeItemholder) viewHolder;         


    mHomeItemholder.mImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Handle your code
        }
    });

}       



public int getBasicItemCount() {
    return mItemList == null ? 0 : mItemList.size();
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return getBasicItemCount(); // header

}
```

}

Comment: I am so sorry, But i am not able to figure how to make it work with my code.